# is there a function ( IndicatorRemove() just like ExpertRemove() ) to remove an indicator from chart if an indicator has expired?

Tags: mql4

```
   datetime startTime = D'24.01.2014';
   datetime endTime = D'15.09.2020 13:00';
   if(TimeCurrent()>=endTime){
      Alert("This EA has expired....Call 08145301211 for new order");
      IndicatorRemove();
   }
```

i only know about ExpertRemove(); that will remove an EA from chart. can someone help me i want to do the same for an indicator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [ChartIndicatorDelete](https://docs.mql4.com/chart_operations/chartindicatordelete) is what you are looking for.